# Vaadin 23 add social share buttons and Google Analytics

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin23

Is it possible to add to the Vaadin 23 application social share buttons? Like for example https://sharethis.com/ This website provides JavaScript code which should be embedded into the application. Is it possible to embed this code into the Vaadin 23 application and if so, could you please show how?

The same question and for Google Analytics.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: The main issue is that I have no idea right now how to embed the custom JavaScript into the application

Comment: For Google Analytics You could add the JavaScript code to the index.html

Comment: Thanks, I added both - Google Analytics and Social Share plugin via index.html!